# Rotating a Text Field in as3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I am working on a Flash Project in which i have to rotate a text field.I am Rotating the text field using this function---

```
**function rotateAroundCenter(ob:*, angleDegrees)
{

    var m:Matrix = ob.transform.matrix;
    m.tx -=  point.x;
    m.ty -=  point.y;
    m.rotate(angleDegrees*(Math.PI/180));
    m.tx +=  point.x;
    m.ty +=  point.y;
    ob.transform.matrix = m;
}**
```

**var point:Point = new Point(mc.x+ mc.width / 2,mc.y+ mc.height / 2);**

---

i am calculating the center point of mc containing the textfield using the above method.

I Have also povided the dragging feature so that one can drag the text field.
 The problem is when i rotate the text field say 45 degrees and then  i drag it to other position now if i rotate the text field again it is not rotating about its center or origin, it rotates about some other point that is calculated by the same method ***---mc.x+ mc.width / 2,mc.y+ mc.height / 2---***

How do i calculate the perfect origin of a  text field at any angle of rotation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the search, man... [here](http://lucamezzalira.com/2008/02/07/little-tricks-to-rotate-images-in-flex/) is example with Rotate effect. You can adapt the math from there.

Answer (score 1):

You're rotating mc or textfield? If you're rotating textfield, so you have to get width from it. 
Rotating textfield and dragging mc is best for performance.

```
rotateAroundCenter(textField, 45);
var point:Point = new Point(textField.width / 2, textField.height / 2);
```